# zipArchive with MAMP?

Tags: php, installation, mamp, php-ziparchive

trying to work out how to install zipArchive extension with MAMP, but not having much luck

any know how to do this? I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for completeness.

JUST UPGRADE MAMP!!!

Sorry for shouting ;)

Answer (score 0):

First three Google results indicate that MAMP comes compiled without ZIP extension:

- http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8287
- http://symphony-cms.com/discuss/thread/512/
- http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9300 - MAMP Zip Extension Install Guide

Answer (score 0):

**Mamp** is a product that wraps PHP / MySQL etc within one easy package for the mac, and has nothing to do with the extension

the extension runs within PHP, so your questions should be how should i use the zipArchive with PHP

the answer to that questions is read the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

To install an extension is very straight forward, just drop the extension within the extensions folder and then restart PHP.